# Error: "Use of declared type 'CAPSMenu' "

Tags: xcode, swift, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, viewcontroller

I've gone ahead and add this Pod via CocoaTouch and add it to my master view controller. For some reason it is not recognizing it. Why am I receiving this error that it is undeclared?

So far I've only added this Pod and Firebase to my Xcode project.

[Xcode Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pHzzR.png)

[Tutorial Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtWvg.png)

Comment: This is the Github of the pod I am trying to add to my project.  https://github.com/HighBay/PageMenu#how-to-use-pagemenu

Comment: gone ahead from what/where?

Comment: I've gone ahead and add it to my project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've not added `CAPSPageMenu.swift` in your project at all. Clone that repo and add that file from `Classes` folder. You'll be good to go. That way you won't have to use pods to use it in your project.

Comment: So even though I did a 'pod install' via the Terminal it hasn't add the CAPSPageMenu.swift to my project?

Comment: Just doing the pod install won't do the job. You need to write a podfile first. Then you should run pod install. Have you done that? Because I don't see that pod in your Xcode screenshot.

Comment: Yes I added the pod 'PageMenu' to my Podfile then ran a 'pod install'

Comment: Instead of using pods do like I said. It's pretty straight forward. Drag that file into your Xcode project right below appdelegate.swift and select copy selected items when a prompt is shown.

Comment: Anytime. :) Happy coding.